# Integrate qlik sense API into my application

Tags: javascript, qliksense

I'm currently developing a web app where I would like to add qlik sense utilities into it.

The thing is even after reading all the different documentations about it I still find it ambiguous how to implement qlik sense API.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you done? Do you have some code?

Comment: hello @RPichioli thanks for the interest here is what i've done : https://github.com/speeta/qlik-test
I want to know if i must run the html page under the same server/port as qlik sense dev-hub coudn't i just run it elsewhere ? 
Thanks

Comment: You're welcome @H.E, I don't know too much about qlik and it's ambient configurations. The JS is missing a last "});", the console is warning something about syntax?

Comment: @RPichioli i've been able to make my code work the only problem that i have now is how to use what i have without needing the qlik sense's desktop app

Comment: Hmm sure, it's really strange to make WEB apps dependending on Desktop local apps. I'll try to find something that can help you.

Comment: @RPichioli ok thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

The Qlik Sense content can be embedded through

1. iFrame integration using the App Integration API (single integration)
2. Div integration using the Capability APIs.(provided by qlik)

**Method 1**

First method would be pretty easier

References: https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/3.0/Subsystems/Mashups/Content/AppIntegrationAPI/app-integration-api-examples.htm

- step 1: login to qlik sense desktop, navigate to single api. 
  Single api is app provider by qlik sense to identify qlik applications with specific application ID.
- step 2: get the application ID which you need.
- step 3: use IFrame in HTML page to embed qlik objects.
   
  Paste the iframe tag in a html page and set the height and width
- step 4: 
  Example ApplicationID would be like this: `2fd30673-866d-4bb6-b3be-c5708555ee1f`

**Method 2**

Using Capabality API 
 
Configure web application to communicate with qlik server. Host and port number of the qlik server should be defined.

Using java script in a html 

Sample javascript code :

```
var config = {
    host: "myhost.com",
    prefix: "/",
    port: window.location.port,
    isSecure: true
};
require(["js/qlik"], function(qlik) {
    // open the app
    var app = qlik.openApp("c31e2aba-3b46-4b13-8b87-c5c2514dea1d", config);
    // insert Qlik objects into the page.
    app.getObject(document.getElementById("divID"), "objectID");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps to connect qlik sense server using api 
1.Open qlik sense desktop
 2.Navigate to mashup editop 
 3. Create new app or edit existing app 
 4. Select qlik sense application from App Dropdown 
 5.Open the auto generated js file- this file contains code to connect qlik server using api and embed the qlik objects in a web application. 
 :>)

Answer (score -1):

In addition you can also checkout http://integration.qlik.com

Checkout the documentation or the slide generator on web integration

Also this workshop explains the options:
https://youtu.be/FHQRaYOogiU

Comment: Please add the most important contents of linked stuff into the answer so it will be useable after the links will be gone stale, see [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)